# Documentation needed on how to get FXCop running with Sonarqube 5.1

Tags: c#, plugins, fxcop, sonarqube5.1

On the sonarqube website the new C# plugin documentation states ['native support for fxcop'](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin)

However there is no explanation how to get fxcop running. It does not work out of the box.

What i did so far and works:

- installed Sonarqube 5.1
- using msbuild.sonarqube.runner
- The sonarqube C#,xml,js analysis al work like a charm.

What does not work is using fxcop rules.When i enable 1 rule i get the runner to give the following exception:

> ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution 
>   org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
>            at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLaunc 
>   her.java:91)
>          at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
>          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>          at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
>          at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
>          at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102
>
> ```
>    at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
>    at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
>    at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
>    at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The property "sonar.cs.fxcop.a
> ```
>
> ssembly" must be set and the project must have been built to execute
>   FxCop ru  les. This property can be automatically set by the Analysis
>   Bootstrapper for  Visual Studio Projects plugin, see:
>   http://docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg.If you  wish to skip the analysis of
>   not built projects, set the property "sonar.visu 
>   alstudio.skipIfNotBuilt".

What i tried so far:

- followed the provided docs.codehaus.org/x/TAA1Dg link but this is a dead link. It states "All Codehaus services have been terminated".
- added sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly property to the sonarqube.analysis.xml but this does not change anything to the error.
- added sonar.cs.fxcop.installdirectory property to the sonarqube.analysis.xml file. This changes the error messages to:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find the
>   assembly "C:\p 
>   rojects\mercurial\ccvs.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\"FxCopCmd.exe""
>   provided by the property "sonar.cs.fxcop.assembly".

- But i'm unable to the the fxcop installation copied to this folder. I also failed to influence the path to be redirected to my fxcop installation which comes with vs2013(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\FxCopCmd.exe)
- Another thing is that the sonar-project.properties file next to the .sln file is not picked up by this new msbuild sonar runner thats why i edit the xml file.

In short a step-by-step on the guide how to get fxcop working together with sonarqube 5.1 and the msbuild sonarrunner on the site of sonarqube would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you should read 
http://www.sonarqube.org/easy-analysis-of-visual-studio-solutions-with-the-sonarqube-scanner-for-msbuild/
and
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin .

Pay attention to the fact that you should run the commands from a "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2013 or higher" (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).
Neither DOS Command Prompt nor Windows PowerShell work because they don't set the proper variables.

The FxCop native support doesn't mean that it comes with MSBuild SonarQube Runner, but you have to install Visual Studio >= 2013 (as I think you understood from your message).

Moreover, I found that not only sonar-project.properties has been deprecated, but you have to remove it to avoid strange behaviors.